# I hear a soft click on external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, clicking-sound

I hear a soft click every 20-30 seconds from my external hard drive. I don't think it is the "click of death" but it is giving me some concern.

I've tried chkdsk only to cancel it after 15 hours (read that this was too long).

Is this click a natural click or an indication my drive is falling off soon? fyi, the drive is about 1 year old enterprise drive.

Comment: What drive? - give make and model. What's the drive doing at the time? Can you make an audio recording, upload it somewhere and [edit] a link in?

Comment: How large of a disk?  15 hours on a 10 TB drive is less of a concern then 16 hours on a 500 GB HDD.

Comment: I'd advise you to check the HDD's health and SMART status using the manufacturer's brand-specific diagnostic tool, @noman! I'd also strongly recommend you to backup your data from that drive somewhere else ASAP before you start troubleshooting the issue. I'd also check the warranty on the hard drive, if it's still covered you might be able to RMA it and get a replacement from the manufacturer's customer support. Keep us posted!

Answer (score 1):

I have in my head 2 possible variants

- The problem is with power supply of hard drive, check or change A/C that polarity and voltage match.
- Bad sectors. When the head flies over a hard drive platter, it 'detects' a bad sector on the platter causing the clicking sound to appear. The problem is that soon might be pauses during read-and-write operation — that  happened with my hard drive. It just froze for seconds during the operation. I guess that bad sector just came bigger in some time and my so hard drive died after 3 years. I would recommend either forget and get used to sound waiting for it to die, or if it's on guarantee — ask to change hard drive, because the problem will lead to falling off in some time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to record the sound given off from the Seagate 2TB hard drive. What I have done is switch it to another bay. Strangely enough, the click has been reduced or the sound of the click has gone down (?). It takes a close ear to hear it now. fyi, the drive that took that spot doesn't seem to be making any noise.

I will try to monitor it over the next couple of weeks.